# `gio open` fails to use its own mime config

Tags: gnome, mime-types, xfce4, xdg, glib

I'm struggling with `gio` failing to open an url using default browser under XFCE4 desktop environment. What could be the reason and how to fix it?

`gio info http://google.com` identifies the link as `text/html` type:

```
$ gio info http://google.com
display name: /
display name: /
type: regular
uri: http://google.com
attributes:
  standard::type: 1
  standard::display-name: /
  standard::edit-name: /
  standard::icon: text-html, text-x-generic, text-html-symbolic, text-x-generic-symbolic
  standard::content-type: text/html
  standard::fast-content-type: text/html
  standard::symbolic-icon: text-html-symbolic, text-x-generic-symbolic, text-html, text-x-generic
  id::filesystem: http:uri=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com
```

`gio mime text/html` reports the correct default browser for the type:

```
$ gio mime text/html
Default application for “text/html”: sidekick-browser.desktop
Registered applications:
    sidekick-browser.desktop
    calibre-ebook-edit.desktop
    chromium.desktop
    firefox.desktop
    emacs.desktop
    emacsclient.desktop
    okularApplication_txt.desktop
    org.xfce.mousepad.desktop
    vim.desktop
Recommended applications:
    sidekick-browser.desktop
    calibre-ebook-edit.desktop
    chromium.desktop
    firefox.desktop
```

But `gio open http://google.com` opens the link in Chromium, which is not a default browser according to `gio info`.

At the same time, `xdg-open` opens the link in Sidekick browser which conforms to settings.